# Javascript window.print print blank page sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

im working with google chrome, for print a dynamic web, im working with kiosk-printing them i have my shortcut like this `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing` the problem is sometime print my data, but sometimes print a blank page, and the time comes when you print more times blank data, which is bad because i use a id for each ticket, really i try printing with other web example [this web for test print](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print), and so does
, but here i put my code

```
var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;    
var nhtml ='<html><head></title><style> @page{size:auto;margin:4mm;}@media print { body {font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;list-style:none;font-weight:bold }}'

nhtml=nhtml+'.stylo1{width:88mm;border-bottom:1px solid #333;border-top:1px solid #333;}.left{float:left;}';
nhtml=nhtml+'</style></head><body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11pt;list-style:none;font-weight:bold"><div style="width:88mm;list-style:none;"><center></center>';
    
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             nhtml=nhtml+ '<li><div class="stylo1">' + //data  +'</div></li>';
             for(var j = 0; j < data.Items.length; j++) {
                nhtml=nhtml+'<li><div class="detalle">'here i put data'</div></li><br>';
             }
            
            }
        
        
        document.body.innerHTML =nhtml;
        window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},100);
```

please i need fix it i have angry customers :)